# Can't run scripts through console in QPython

Tags: python, qpython

I'm using the app QPython, and while it's easy to run scripts from a file, I'm struggling to see how to load a script into the Console so that I can use it there (e.g. to use functions defined in a script).

I'm not very familiar with Python, so I don't know whether I'm having difficulty with Python or with the app. As far as I know in ordinary Python, the command "import script" will import all of the code in the file script.py, which has to be contained in the directory you loaded Python from (this is already concerning as I can't change the directory in QPython).

For the record, the equivalent command in Haskell (which I am familiar with) would be :l script.hs

Answer (score 0):

To import some functions :

```
from script import functiona, functionb()
```

To import all functions from a script use :

```
from script import *
```

You could just do :

```
import script
```

But then you'll have to call your functions like that :

```
script.myfunction()
```

Comment: Right, that at least answers my question about python - am I right that the script has to be in that specific directory (the one you load python in)? If so, I can't change the directory I'm in in the ap

Comment: Sorry, *If so, I can't do that in the app - do you have any advice?

Comment: yes, same directory, or in python libraries directories